# for loop jumps to last number in java android development

Tags: java, android, database, for-loop, logic

Hi I am making an android App, I want to add some values to a database and I want to do N times so I used a for loop as seen below:

```
private void addCodeToDataBase() {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        //indexnumber is a TextView
        indexNumber.setText("Please enter the TAN code for Index number " + i);
        //tanCode is an EditText
        if (tanCode.getText().toString() != null) {
        //index here is just an int so i can use the i inside the onClick
            index = i;
         //add is a button
            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String codeText = tanCode.getText().toString();
                    dbHandler.addcode(index, codeText);
                }
            });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(addcode.this, "Please enter your code !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

but what I am facing here is the for loop jumps to 100 at the first run, What I mean is the text will show :

> Please enter the TAN code for Index number 100

it skips 99 numbers!! how would I fix it ?

Comment: This is happening because you have put `add.setOnClickListener` inside of your `for` loop and by the time you hit the add button the loop has already executed making the value of `i = 100`.

Comment: No that is not correct...the for loop is working perfectly..the problem is that you are not pausing the execution for each iteration and thus it does all the executions in one go..that is, the for loop works from 1 to 100, but you can see just the 100th one because the for loop has been finshed at 100..

Comment: any ideas on how to fix it ?? @Lal

Answer (score 0):

It's Because your for loop executes so fast that you can't notice that the change of the text.First i is 0,and then it becomes 1,then the text will be "Please enter the TAN code for Index number 1" ......

Comment: and what do you recommend on fixing this issue?

Comment: What do you want,do you want index increases only click **add** button ?

Comment: what I want to do is to add a 100 TAN codes inside a table in a database and I want the user to do it manually for the first time the application is run. so I was thinking of using the for loop option so it can do the process for 100 times.

Comment: You mean you want add these one by one,you should add continue your loop only the onClick method is invoked,that means when user add a code,and then next,otherwise the index won't change.

Answer (score 0):

your loop is working correctly but it is replacing text on each iteration that's why you think that it is jumping on last value please use break point and debug you will see each value on each iteration or use log in which you will see each value

Comment: if you think to show each in foreground then please use array or list add these in it and then show in recycler view or list view

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to imagine what your code does without seeing your declarations of `indexNumber`, `tanCode`, `index`, and, in particular, `add`. So, e.g., we don't know how often your if condition yields true.

However, most probably, the problem is that your assignment `add.setOnClickListener(...)` is just iterated with no user interaction in between. Now if you repeatedly assign something to your `add` (whatever that is), the last assignment will win.

If you want 100 buttons, you'll need to have an array or List of buttons to press, where each has a different tan code. If you want one button that repeatedly asks for the different tans, then you have to assign the data for click i + 1 only after click i has been handled, i.e. in the on click listener.

To give more specific help, we would need to know how your user interface should look (how many widgets of what kind) and how each widget should behave.